# Duplicate class found error for multiple implementations

Tags: android, firebase

I have been trying to add ML Kit dependencies so I can use it in my code, but I keep getting duplicate class error.

These are my dependencies now:

```
implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:32.0.0')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx:21.2.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database-ktx:20.2.1-ktx'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:21.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision-automl:18.0.6'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision-image-label-model:20.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:20.0.0'

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision:24.0.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision-barcode-model:16.1.1'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.8.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.3.1'
    implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.5.1'
    implementation platform('androidx.compose:compose-bom:2022.10.00')
    implementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui'
    implementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-graphics'
    implementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview'
    implementation 'androidx.compose.material3:material3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
    androidTestImplementation platform('androidx.compose:compose-bom:2022.10.00')
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4'
    debugImplementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling'
    debugImplementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-manifest'
```

And when I remove these everything works well:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:21.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision-automl:18.0.6'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision-image-label-model:20.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:20.0.0'

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision:24.0.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision-barcode-model:16.1.1'
```

Actually, when I just put that firebase-core dependency I get this error a bunch of times:

```
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzdu found in modules firebase-analytics-impl-16.1.1-runtime (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:16.1.1) and play-services-measurement-sdk-api-21.2.2-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-sdk-api:21.2.2)
```

I have tried excluding some groups, changing some upgrades, but nothing seems to work. I feel like I am wasting my time on nothing... It is really frustrating and I have no idea what to try anymore. Same thing happens when I try to implement the newest Material 3 version instead of the enlisted one.

Comment: Try removing just the measurament-sdk-api